# Filter on date stored in integer fields without datetime

Tags: sql, date, filter

I've got two columns, one with a year (e.g. 2013, 2014) and one with a number of the month (e.g. 2, 3, 4).

Is there code that I could use to bring back the previous 12 months from my selected month? So if I selected my year as '2014' and my month as '9', I'd like to bring back the results going back to year '2013' and month '10'.

Is that possible without having a datetime field?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible.  I would do this with "month" arithmetic.  For instance, to get all dates since 2013-10, for selected month 2014-09:

```
select t.*
from table t
where year*12 + month >= 2014*12 + 9 - 12;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was after.